# Using div's to pad a webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a div to push the contents of a webpage down by 150px (the space will be used for a header image later that I don't yet have).

However because the div is blank or empty, browsers are in effect, ignoring it.

The html:

```
<body>
<div id="header_block"></div>
 .... rest of document....
```

The CSS:

```
#header_block{width:100%;height:150px;min-height:150px}
```

The rest of the document works fine, but, even when I get the header graphic, its going to be applied as a background image.

Is there any way to stop the browser from ignoring this header_block because it thinks its empty?

Comment: You want to display the `#header_block` right? It works in the example. What's the rest of your code, could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your example?

Comment: if you're explicitly setting the height in the CSS then it wont hide when empty. If it *is* hiding and you've specified that CSS, you've probably included your CSS file incorrectly.

Comment: Works fine in my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is give the main `<div>` a `margin-top:150px` ; that will push it 150px down from it's position in the flow then you should be good to go insofar as making your background image appear.

Comment: Okay, this worked, and will work fine, Im annoyed at myself for not thinking of it myself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use trans.gif (a blank small image) using width and height according to your need. Then proper space will set.

Regards,
Arun Kumar

Comment: I know about transparent gif's, its a technique thats quite ancient in web-development, and a technique I wanted to avoid if possible, however, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#header_block{width:100%; border:1px solid;height:150px;min-height:150px}
```

So that you will get a look for header_block.

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't hide if you've set their height explicitly via CSS. If it *is* hiding you've got other problems, likely due to a typo or incorrectly linking a stylesheet.

If you need a placeholder image, I use http://placehold.it/ which I find very convenient.

<sub>I have no affiliation with **placehold.it**</sub>

Something like https://placehold.it/300x100 gets you:

[image: placholder image]

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for that placehold.it. Thats going to be very useful. I never knew about it at all :)